Flutter Firebase Firestore how to use withConverter() in .then() call
I have this call to firestore:
fireDb
    .collection(FIRE_DB_ROOT_JOBS)
    .doc(fireAuthUseCases.getEmail())
    .collection(FIRE_DB_LATEST_JOBS)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
    latestJobsDocId = snapshot.docs[0].id;
  }
}),

I then take latestJobsDocId to again make another call to firestore to then call withConverter() like this:
fireDb
    .collection(FIRE_DB_ROOT_JOBS)
    .doc(fireAuthUseCases.getEmail())
    .collection(FIRE_DB_LATEST_JOBS)
    .doc(latestJobsDocId)
    .withConverter<LatestStoredJobsEntity>(
    ...
    ...

I tried to figure out how to eliminate  the second call and just call with converter inside the .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) , but I could not get the withConverter to work properly. I tried:
snapshot.docs[0].reference.withConverter<LatestStoredJobsEntity>(
  fromFirestore: LatestStoredJobsEntity.fromFirestore, 
  toFirestore: (LatestStoredJobsEntity jobsEntity, _) => jobsEntity.toFirestore(), 
);


But it returns WithConverterDocumentReference instead of WithConverterDocumentSnapshot that can call .data(). How can I accomplish this with one call to FB?

"but did not work" - what exactly did it do that a was different than you expect?  Please edit the question to share your debugging details.

You might be able to adapt the calling sequence shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78874885/12507984.

@DougStevenson edited as advised.

This looks like a XY problem. What is the use-case that you're trying to accomplish here?

@Dan R pointed me in the right direction , I simply had to map the doc LinkedHashMap<String,dynamic> to my Class data :
factory LatestStoredJobsEntity.fromDoc(
    Map<String, dynamic> data,
  ) {
    return LatestStoredJobsEntity(
      onSiteTitles: data['onSiteTitles'],
      onSiteUrls: data['onSiteUrls'],
      remoteTitles: data['remoteTitles'],
      remoteUrls: data['remoteUrls'],
    );
  }

